# How Can I Comment a Block of Text in Microsoft Office Visual Basic Editor?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, vba, macros

Sometimes when I'm writing a macro in Excel's Visual Basic Editor (VBE), I want to comment out a block of code to test the macro without it. I know I could go to each line and type an apostrophe (`'`), but this is tedious! Can I do this for a larger block?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this warranted a -1, but thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there's an easy way to do this in the VBE, but it requires you enable a button (or two) on your toolbar -

1. Right click your toolbar and select *customize*
2. In the *commands* menu, select the *edit* category and about halfway down you will see two options -

   **Comment Block** and **Uncomment Block**
3. Select these and drag them up to the toolbar.

Now when you highlight code you can click **Comment Block** to comment it out and **Uncomment Block** to un-comment it.

[image]

*Note: as of Office 2010 VBA, there is no keyboard shortcut for these functions*